# is it possible to run any os on just 90% of the screen

Tags: windows, ubuntu, operating-system

I have a black spot on right side on screen. I am not able to see things behind it..is it possible to run a window such that it always takes only certain percentage of screen in certain side.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, create a program that calls `SHAppBarMessage`. This will allow you to create a taskbar-style window that is not covered by normal/maximized applications. Full-screen video and games will ignore it however...

Comment: if i run a video through chrome on full screen will it ignore it?